# My code for creating an admin option doesn't work

Tags: admin, dashboard, options

I used the code provided in [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-create-a-wordpress-global-options-page--wp-24570) to create an option menu in dashboard, but contrary to what was expected, I don't see any new menu in dashboard:

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_global_custom_options');
function add_global_custom_options()
{
    add_options_page('Global Custom Options', 'Global Custom Options', 'manage_options', 'functions','global_custom_options');
}
function global_custom_options()
{
?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Global Custom Options</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options') ?>
            <p><strong>Twitter ID:</strong><br />
                <input type="text" name="twitterid" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('twitterid'); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Store Options" /></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
            <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="twitterid" />
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

What did I do wrong? I added this code in my child theme's `functions.php`.

Comment: It should be adding "Global Custom Options" under the "Settings" menu - check it's definitely not there. And if so, are you the user account you're signed in as has the correct permissions (for `manage_options` you need Administrator on a default install).

Comment: Yes, administrator. And I checked again, "Global Custom Options" appears nowhere. Is it possible that the commercial theme on top of which runs my child theme is somehow overriding this code of mine?

Comment: Possibly. Try something more unique than `functions` for your menu slug.

Comment: Oh wait it does work! I understood your "under the Settings menu" as meaning visually, not "in" it. But it's there, thanks TheDeadMedic ! Is it easy to put this options directly in the left sidebar, not nested in the Settings menu?

Comment: You need `add_menu_page` instead of `add_options_page` :)

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer so that the question can be marked resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure Your Functions, Slug and Callback Functions are Unique(Means Different from any other plugin or default WordPress). Also to save options use Settings API
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_unique_custom_options');
function add_unique_custom_options()
{
    add_options_page('Global Custom Options', 'Global Custom Options', 'manage_options', 'unique-functions','unique_custom_options');
}
function unique_custom_options()
{
?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Global Custom Options</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options') ?>
            <p><strong>Twitter ID:</strong><br />
                <input type="text" name="twitterid" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('twitterid'); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Store Options" /></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
            <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="twitterid" />
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a top-level menu page, you need to use `add_menu_page` instead of `add_options_page` (which adds a sub-menu item to the "Settings" menu).

```
add_menu_page(
    $page_title,
    $menu_title,
    $capability,
    $menu_slug,
    $callback_function,
    $icon_url,
    $menu_position
);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page